# How to work with Clipboard in ASP.NET, Server side

Tags: c#, asp.net, clipboard

Is there any way to working with `Clipboard` in `ASP.NET`, in `Server-side`?
I want to push something in `Clipboard` & fetch it.

EXTRA INFO:
I had some search and found out, the solution is working with `Thread`. but I'm looking for another way, *if is there another way*.

**UPDATE:**
Please answer to following questions:

1. Can I work with thread when I'm working with clipboard?
2. If so, can I run new thread when I'm working with clipboard more than one time withing single process (imaging user clicked on a button and I have to push 100 data in clipboard withing a for (loop))

For example:

Option 1:

```
void myMethod(object i){        
    // put something on clipboard and get that        
}

protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for(int i=0; i<100; i++){
         Thread t = new Thread(myMethod);
         t.Start(i);
    }
}
```

Option 2:

```
void myMethod(){        
    for(int i=0; i<100; i++){
        // put something on clipboard and get that        
    }
}

protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     Thread t = new Thread(myMethod);
     t.Start();        
}
```

Which one is correct?

Comment: why do you ever need clipboard for web server side?

Comment: In my case, I have to

Comment: Please explain what you have to do with instead of your possible solution. Clipboard server-side is pretty unusual...

Comment: I know, but if you are looking for another solution instead of using clipboard, there is no other way, and I have to use of `Clipboard`.

Comment: So what have you tried? what doesnt work?

Comment: please check this question for more details, thanks ! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30283675/how-to-work-with-clipboard-in-asp-net-i-used-thread-for-that-btw

Comment: They refer to `Other programmers on the web`, that answered to the question. before posting this questions, I had some search about using Clipboard withing an asp.net and found that the answer is: using thread, I mean

Comment: 1. Yes! you need to run a new thread with STA attribute, otherwise Clipboard calls won't work.
2. Rephrase question, cannot be understood.

Comment: It is always better if you can process 100 data in a single new thread than processing 100 data by spawning 100 new threads (if that was the second question). However, my solution in answer can handle both situations (uses `lock`).

Comment: Both options are correct, but option 2 is better.

Comment: are you sure both are correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you do it:

```
    public static void PdfToJpg()
    {
        var Thread = new Thread(PdfToJpgThread);
        Thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
        Thread.Start(); // You can pass your custom data through Start if you need
    }
    private static readonly object PdfToJpgLock = new object();
    private static void PdfToJpgThread(object Data)
    {
        lock (PdfToJpgLock)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
            {

                // Call to Acrobat CopyToClipboard
                // ...

                Clipboard.GetImage().Save(outputPath, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
                Clipboard.Clear();

                // ...
            }
        }
    }
```

For each button click, just call `PdfToJpg()` and you are done.

Comment: you right bro, I think I need to start new thread, If i need work with clipboard for new iteration of loop, as I wrong?

Comment: Why do you need a semaphore? To prevent running multiple parallel pdf to image generators?

Comment: I just edited my comment, if there is no need to starting new thread for working with Clipboard, so I'm on wrong way, please answer to this question first

Comment: after some edit, this code worked fine, but I marked your answer as answer !thanks :)