# Insufficient Memory Exception in Interop library when exporting images of PPT slide

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, powerpoint, office-interop

I want to export an image from a Powerpoint presentation using Microsoft.Office.Interop Library:

```
Application pptApplication = new Application();
Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Presentation pptPresentation = pptApplication.Presentations.Open(fileurl, MsoTriState.msoFalse, MsoTriState.msoFalse, MsoTriState.msoFalse);
pptPresentation.Slides[1].Export(fullPath + thumbfileName, ".jpg", 800, 600);
pptPresentation.Close();
System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(pptPresentation);
```

It throws an Insufficient Memory Exception on Live Server, although it works fine in development environment. Any suggestions?

Comment: try the resolution from this https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vsod/2009/03/16/word-2003-sp3-throws-intermittent-error-there-is-insufficient-memory-save-the-document-now/

Answer (score 0):

Consider using [Open XML SDK](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb448854.aspx) for dealing with open XML documents instead. See [Working with presentation slides (Open XML SDK)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg278332.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) for more information.

Microsoft does not currently recommend, and does not support, Automation of Microsoft Office applications from any unattended, non-interactive client application or component (including ASP, ASP.NET, DCOM, and NT Services), because Office may exhibit unstable behavior and/or deadlock when Office is run in this environment.

If you are building a solution that runs in a server-side context, you should try to use components that have been made safe for unattended execution. Or, you should try to find alternatives that allow at least part of the code to run client-side. If you use an Office application from a server-side solution, the application will lack many of the necessary capabilities to run successfully. Additionally, you will be taking risks with the stability of your overall solution. Read more about that in the [Considerations for server-side Automation of Office](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/257757/considerations-for-server-side-automation-of-office) article.

Comment: Thanks for reply  Eugene, But the required output can not be generated using the OpenXML,So i have to use alternate way. Any Ideas about Generating Image from PPT Slides ?

Comment: I'm hesitant to suggest this, but perhaps copying the slide to the clipboard and then retrieving the image may work.  See this answer: [http://stackoverflow.com/a/30286108/2592875](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30286108/2592875)